# Can i publish android studio project on iphone app store?

Tags: android, ios, publishing

I am still a beginner and I really don't know much and am working on my first app on android studio.
So is it possible to publish android studio project on iPhone App Store? If not is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot publish a packaged compiled .apk Android Package file to an IOS app store. But an IPA file to IOS store

**Google Play**: - For Google play store you need to register for a  Google play dev console account, plus a stock & rooted version of Android latest OS build phone

See [this](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/)

**Apple Store**: - You need to have a Mac, plus an Apple developer license. A code editor like XCode, a know-how of programming language like *Swift 3*, an SDK toolkit & an iPhone

See [Link1](https://developer.apple.com/programs/how-it-works/) and [Link2](https://developer.apple.com/develop/).

Answer (score 1):

android application is mainly build based on java program. ios application is build based on objective C.Its not because of programming language but rather due to final package its get compressed.

You can try learning [xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) cross platform native app development.

or

use [ionic 2](https://ionicframework.com/) framework. App Development based on HTML5,jss,css. Which use simple webview to display the content. That can be converted to any platform.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it as both have platform specific. So use their respective platform so audience can reach easily.

Mixing up of different platform caused confusion so follow each website rules.